# How to Send custom email for customer registration in magento?

Tags: php, email, magento

I have created a custom template for `customer registration`, but I don't know how to call it when I register a customer.

I have created a custom email template like this:

```
<template>
    <email>
        <vendor_suggestions_email_template translate="label">
            <label>Vendor Suggestions</label>
            <file>vendor_suggestions.html</file>
            <type>html</type>
        </vendor_suggestions_email_template >
    </email>
</template>
```

My custom email template is loading in admin panel, I have checked it. Now I want to call this email for `customer registration`. So I have to overwrite my customer model from `mage/customer/model/customer.php` file to my local customer module.

Here is the customer model code for sending email for `customer registration`

```
const XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/create_account/email_template';

public function sendNewAccountEmail($type = 'registered', $backUrl = '', $storeId = '0')
{
    $types = array(
        'registered'   => self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is disabled
        'confirmed'    => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is enabled
        'confirmation' => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // email with confirmation link
    );
    if (!isset($types[$type])) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Wrong transactional account email type'));
    }

    if (!$storeId) {
        $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId($this->getSendemailStoreId());
    }

    $this->_sendEmailTemplate($types[$type], self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
        array('customer' => $this, 'back_url' => $backUrl), $storeId);

    return $this;
}
```

Now, I don't know what should I do to send my customer email template for `customer registration`. I really don't understand how the above code works for sending email in customer registration and how to trigger my custom email template.

Can anyone help me????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your custom template in `System >> Transactional Email` section in backend.

Then You need to assign that Email Template for Customer Registration from

`System >> Configuration >> Customer Configuration`

In create new Account options block select custom email template in `Default Welcome Email` select box and save config. then Magento will use your custom email template for customer registration.

Comment: This is will work. I want to do this programmatically by overwriting customer model. Can you tell me how to do that?